# Python - Compare a column of dates in two CSV files and keep those in common

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSV files of unequal length that have a column that looks like this:

CSV 1

```
EntryDate
9/3/10
9/27/10
10/5/10
10/11/10
10/20/10
10/25/10
```

CSV 2

```
EntryDate
9/7/10
9/27/10
10/11/10
11/3/10
```

I'd like to compare the two files and return the dates that they have in common. I started with this in Python 3 to create two data frames of the columns in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

fields = ["StartDate"]
f1= "f1.csv"
df1 = pd.read_csv(f1, skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)

f2 = "f2.csv"
df2 = pd.read_csv(f2, skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
```

I tried pd.merge and difflib, but it didn't work. I've tried others with no luck as well. Help or direction appreciated.

Comment: Are the files sorted by date?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both files are sorted.

preps:

- Open each file, `file1` and `file2`
- [call next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on the files to skip the header
- call next on the files to get the first line from each file

the rest:

- convert line from each file to a [datetime object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) so they can be compared
- if the dates are equal,

  - save one in a container, maybe a list
  - call next on each file to get the next lines from each
- if `file1` line is greater than `file2` line,

  - call next on `file2` and get its next line
- if `file1` line is less than `file2` line,

  - call next on `file1` and get its next line
- repeat till StopIteration raised by one of the files